# Linq Query using navigation properties and Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am trying to compose a linq query using navigation properties.  I am selecting properties from 3 entities:

- Lockers
- SectionColumn
- Contracts

I require ALL rows from the Lockers table where all the following conditions are met: the LockerTypeId = "308", .OutOfOrder != true, x.SectionColumn.SectionId == "52").

The query below without the condition x.SectionColumn.SectionId == "52" works and returns exactly what I require except rows with Section id of any value are returned as I would expect.

```
    from l in Lockers.Where(x => x.LockerTypeId == "308" && x.OutOfOrder != 
    true).DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new 
                {
                   ColumnNumber = l.ColumnNumber,
                   LockerTypeId = l.LockerTypeId,
                   OutOfOrder = l.OutOfOrder,
                   Rented = l.Contracts.Select(x => x.Contract_ID < 0 ?                   
                     false : true).FirstOrDefault(),
                   Section = l.SectionColumn.SectionId
                   }
```

When I add the condition 'x.SectionColumn.SectionId == "52"' as below  I get the error "The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null". Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type" in linqpad. SectionId is a string (varchar in SQL Server).

```
    from l in Lockers.Where(x => x.LockerTypeId == "308" && x.OutOfOrder != 
    true).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I would be grateful for assistance in correctly writing this query.

Comment: Please, edit second code sample. There is no `SectionId ` there.

Comment: Section = l.SectionColumn != null?l.SectionColumn.SectionId?0:0

Comment: if SectionColumn is allow null in table schema ?

Comment: Before accessing l.SectionColumn.SectionId you have to check l.SectionColumn is not equal null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your code might be a little more straight forward if you stick to pure LINQ. In that case, your code should look something like the following.

```
 var results = from l in Lockers
               where l.LockerTypeId == "308" && l.OutOfOrder != true && l.SectionColumn.SectionId == "52"
               select new 
               {
                    ColumnNumber = l.ColumnNumber,
                    LockerTypeId = l.LockerTypeId,
                    OutOfOrder = l.OutOfOrder,
                    Rented = l.Contracts.Select(x => x.Contract_ID < 0 ? false : true).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Section = l.SectionColumn.SectionId
               }
```

If `l.SectionColumn.SectionId` represents valid navigational properties and is of type `string`, then this should work correctly.

You really haven't done a thorough job of describing the issue (and it looks like you didn't stick around to field questions), but if `l.SectionColumn` is nullable, you should be able to update your code to something like this.

```
 var results = from l in Lockers
               let sectionId = (l.SectionColumn != null) ? l.SectionColumn.SectionId : null
               where l.LockerTypeId == "308" && l.OutOfOrder != true && sectionId == "52"
               select new 
               {
                    ColumnNumber = l.ColumnNumber,
                    LockerTypeId = l.LockerTypeId,
                    OutOfOrder = l.OutOfOrder,
                    Rented = l.Contracts.Select(x => x.Contract_ID < 0 ? false : true).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Section = l.SectionColumn.SectionId
               }
```

Comment: As long as some SectionColumn is null  values, this solution can not be true

Comment: Before accessing l.SectionColumn.SectionId you have to check l.SectionColumn is not equal null

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a go.

Comment: @محمدالنعيمي: I updated my answer to include that possibility.

Comment: using the standard linq syntax as suggested - the query is now working in linqpad.  No idea why the lambda version did not work.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Samuel: You'll probably agree that the LINQ-only version is also a little clearer. Please remember to flag the answer as correct if it solves your problem.